# how to add a def function with a while true loop

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I've added a function definition to tell my turtle to jump when you press the space bar. There is also a `while True` loop in my code, and whenever the space button is pressed, the `while True` loop freezes momentarily until the jump is finished and then carries on.

I've tried adding the function definition in the `while True` loop and outside. I can only put the function definition before the `while True` loop, because if I put it after the `while True`, the code will never reach it.

```
#making the player jump
def jump():
    player.fd(100)
    player.rt(180)
    player.fd(100)
    player.lt(180)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(jump, "space")
```

I'm expecting the `while True` loop to not freeze, but wherever I've tried putting the `def`, it doesn't seem to work.

I also saw another answer to something similar to this, but didn't understand how I could apply that to my code.

Any other suggestions would be great.

Comment: Just saying, some modules are single threaded, which means they take command by command, and while loops crash them

Answer (score 2):

Until you get that async stuff to work, here's a minimalist implementation using turtle's own timer event to keep an obstacle moving forward, even when jumping:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def jump():
    screen.onkey(None, 'space')  # disable handler inside handler

    if jumper.ycor() == 0:  # if jumper isn't in the air
        jumper.forward(150)
        jumper.backward(150)

    screen.onkey(jump, 'space')

def move():
    hurdle.forward(6)
    if hurdle.xcor() > -400:
        screen.ontimer(move, 100)

jumper = Turtle('turtle')
jumper.speed('slowest')
jumper.penup()
jumper.setheading(90)

hurdle = Turtle('turtle')
hurdle.speed('fastest')
hurdle.penup()
hurdle.setheading(180)
hurdle.setx(400)

screen = Screen()
screen.onkey(jump, 'space')
screen.listen()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

You can find several, more fleshed out versions of this on SO by searching for '[turtle-graphics] jump'

Avoid using a `while True:` loop in turtle's event-based environment.

Answer (score 1):

I expected that it can be hard to do it with `async` but I built example which works.

Inside `jump` I use `asyncio.sleep` so this way when one turtle is sleeping then other turtle can walk. Without `asyncio.sleep` first turtle walk all the time.

```
import asyncio
import turtle

t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()

async def jump1():
    while True:
        t1.fd(100)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
        t1.left(90)


async def jump2():
    while True:
        t2.fd(100)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
        t2.right(90)

tasks = [jump1(), jump2()]

# Python 3.6.7
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()    
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))

# Python 3.7
#asyncio.run(asyncio.wait(tasks))
```

But building something more complex can be more difficult.

I also found [aioturtle](https://github.com/appeltel/aioturtle) - turtle which use `async`. Maybe it will be easier to use `aioturtle`.

Comment: @cdlane I run python 3.7 - maybe there is  the problem. I never used async before but I will try to find solution for this problem.

Comment: @cdlane I made version which works with Python 3.6.7. I don't have older version any more.

Comment: You didn't have to do that--I was going to move to a machine with 3.7!  Update works fine on my 3.6.4.  I appreciate conceptually what it's doing, but visually I don't see anything that I couldn't also do synchronously.  Needs more *wow!* factor.

Comment: @cdlane frankly I start building this code to confirm that it will NOT work or it will be very hard to build it - especially to use async's loop with mainloop. But accidently it works and it wasn't hard to build it. But adding other elements can make problem. But after creating working code I decide to show it even if it not so useful. Normally I would rather create code with `threading` or try to use `ontimer`. `async` needs to build code in different way and it is still new way for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following:
the code for the jump event is called synchronously. That means, everything has to wait for jump() to finish before continuing. this can maybe be fixed by declaring / calling the jump() method asynchronously. This website does a good job of explaining what asynchronous python means and how to implement it: https://hackernoon.com/asynchronous-python-45df84b82434

in short, here's how it would be implemented(in python 3.3 or higher):

```
async def jump():
    #your code here
```

this just makes the jump() function run asynchronously.
now, whenever you call it, you have to call it like this:

```
await jump()
```

this might not work, depending on your exact setup.

i hope this helps.
please, ask me if you have any further questions.

EDIT: example

Comment: thankyouu, im sure it willl help but ill have to read it a couple times to fully understand it

Comment: Sure. I sure know it took me an hour to fully understand :D . it's a lot of information at once.

Comment: I see two problems with this: (1) turtle's functions wasn't created to work asynchronously so `jump` also may not work asynchronously. (2) turtle runs `mainloop()` which works all time and `async` also need to run loop which works all time - so there is problem to work both at the same time.

Comment: I found [aioturtle](https://github.com/appeltel/aioturtle) which use async/await to work but I didn't test it.